# Text after variable print command

Tags: python

At the end of my program, I want the following text to be displayed on the user's screen: "Thanks [StudentName] for participating in the quiz." `StudentName` is the variable with the name of the student (a string).

Here is the single line of code which I attempted to use to achieve this: `print("Thanks", StudentName)`. I'm missing the part "for participating in the quiz" after the student name. What command do I have to input to get this part printed?

Comment: `print("Thanks", StudentName, "for participating in the quiz.")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print("Thanks", StudentName, "for participating in the quiz.")
```

or

```
# will only work if studetName is a string 
# if it's an int for a really weird reason it will throw a TypeError

print("Thanks " + studentName + " for participating in the quiz." )
```

or

```
print("Thanks {} for participating in the quiz.".format(StudentName))
```

or

```
print "Thanks %s for participating in the quiz." % studentName #python2
```

There are several ways to format and print strings in python but the new `str.format()` is the most flexible and in my opinion is easier to read

Comment: your first suggestion includes extra spaces.  `print` automatically inserts a space between adjacent arguments.  you're also inconsistent in your inclusion of a period at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

You want [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print("Thanks {} for participating in the quiz.".format(StudentName))
```